# Javascript: Concat an array while maintaining objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, concatenation

I have two arrays:

```
ArrayOne = new Array(Array1, Array2);
ArrayTwo = new Array(Array3, Array4);
ArrayThree = new Array();
```

I want to do:

```
ArrayThree = ArrayOne.concat(ArrayTwo);
```

With the result:

```
ArrayThree = {ArrayOne, ArrayTwo}
```

However this operation results in:

```
ArrayThree = {ArrayOne[0], ArrayOne[1]... ArrayOne[n], ArrayTwo[0], ArrayTwo[1]... ArrayTwo[n]};
```

Any advice on how to get {ArrayOne, ArrayTwo} so the original array object is maintained?

Thanks

Comment: Backticks (\`) are for inline code. To format a [block of lines as code](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks), indent them an extra four spaces. The "{}" button in the editor toolbar does this for you. Edit your question and try it out. Click the orange question mark in the editor toolbar for more information and tips on formatting.

Answer (score 1):

```
var ArrayThree = [ ArrayOne, ArrayTwo ];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can't use `concat` function...

```
var ArrayThree = [ArrayOne, ArrayTwo];
```

or even,

```
var ArrayThree = new Array(ArrayOne, ArrayTwo);
```

not a problem if you have `ArrayThree` previously initialized

Comment: I think it is because `new Array` is discouraged. But it is not strictly wrong, is it? And the preferred version is also mentioned.

Comment: I didn't know that it's discouraged. Yeah probably because of that

Comment: Downvoted because I believe this answer originally suggested use of the `concat` method, which is exactly what the OP didn't want. If I am mistaken, my apologies.